# multiple conditions Under the 'for' loop

Tags: java, for-loop, java-11, multiple-conditions

Why doesn't the conditional `Boolean` in the standard for loop below behave as expected?
I'm trying to get 3 and 4, indexes 2 and 3 in the array below to print out.  If I try
to specify the range in the condition of the for loop it doesn't run the loop.
To test the conditional in an if condition ( see 2nd listing it works )

Why doesn't it simply work just in the for loop ?

```
int[]weather = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
for(int i=0;i>1&&i<4; i++ ) {
    //if(i>1&&i<4) {
        System.out.println("Weather is ===> "+weather[i]);
    //}
}

nothing printed...
```

---

```
int[]weather = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
for(int i=0;i<10; i++ ) {
    if(i>1&&i<4) {
        System.out.println("Weather is ===> "+weather[i]);
    }
}

Weather is ===> 3
Weather is ===> 4
```

Comment: Because 0 is less than 1 so the loop condition is already false on the first iteration?

Comment: "`for(int i=0;i>1&&i<4; i++ ) {`" the condition is immediately false.

Comment: how can i be greater than 1  when it is set to 0?

Comment: Note that the condition in a loop is used to check whether it should continue running (or start at all) and if the first check returns false (because 0 > 1 is false) it never starts. If that weren't the case, how should the loop "know" when to stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> for(int i=0;i>1&&i<4; i++ ) {
>             ^------^ expression
> ```

For loops execute until the expression is false, and then stop executing. This expression is immediately false (because `0>1` is false), so it immediately stops executing. It doesn't "wait and see" if the expression becomes true again.

If you only want the loop to execute for `i>1&&i<4`:

```
for(int i = 2; i<4; i++ ) {
```

Comment: Thanks.. for some reason I forgot the fact that the loop stops, shuts down immediately upon 1st false.  That the conditional meant stop running.

Answer (score 1):

`for(int i=0;i>1&&i<4; i++ )` dosen't work because since i=0 and it dosen't satisfy the condition in a loop and thus the program never enters the loop.

This is usually used to sometime skip the loop when not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you don't pass the condition after the initialization. At the beginning i is set to 0. The loop continues until i is between 1 and 4 (both excluded), so you never start the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i > 1 && i < 4; i++) {
    // You never goes here because i is 0 so not > than 1
    ...
}
```

Instead if you put the condition inside the loop you bypass execute all the iterations and for some of them you enter the if condition.